# What is the quickest way to enter code in a question

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I know that if a line is preceded by 4 spaces it is treated as code. Is there a quicker way to enter multi line code? It is quite difficult to go to each line of code and add 4 spaces for quite a lot of lines.

is there something equivalent to the vbulleting forums where you used [code] [/code] tags?

Thanks

Comment: Never thought I'd hear someone wishing for a "forum"-style features...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type the code normally, then highlight the block and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> it:

```
code 1;
code 2;
code 3;
```

This is also available on the toolbar as the code `{}` button.

Comment: Brilliant! i cant believe i never knew about this. Thanks!