# What is the proper way to format a posts in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I have been using Stack Overflow for quite a while now and have edited lots of post. 
Each time I edit a post, I end up formatting the code parts by pressing <kbd>space</kbd> 4 times so that it formats the codes properly (in the right way, with the grey background) (hoping you guys got what I mean).

Is it the right way? Since pressing space 4 times in each line of code is bugging me, is there any easier way, or some thing to read on?

Comment: You can select the whole block of code and press the code button.

Comment: Or select the code and press ctrl-K (cmd-K on a Mac).

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101217/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-enter-code-in-a-question?rq=1) and answered also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: It would really help if you go through the [Editing Help page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: thanks guys... going through the links now.. :)... real helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting the "code" button on the markdown editor will allow you to indent/outdent the whole block.

I also use my IDE to format larger blocks/bigger problems (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for Visual Studio users). This can save time, and also helps to catch syntax errors which the OP may have missed. I don't correct such errors (to preserve the integrity of the question), but it may help me propose a solution or leave a helpful comment.

JS Fiddle's "TidyUp" option (recently added) can be handy if you are already have it open and the question pertains to JavaScript, HTML, or CSS.

Comment: thanks... i got the list where everything is properly mentioned.. +1 ..:)

Comment: Yup, definitely a lot of good tools built right into the editor. I wanted to point out how handy an IDE is for cleaning up bigger problems (took me a while to figure that one out).

Comment: `JS Fiddle's "TidyUp" option (recently added) can be handy if you are already have it open`.. yes i started to use tidyup recently..:)..but just thought there will be as such in SO's editor...thanks :)..accepting you answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in two way

1st : Select whole code and hit `code button`

[image]

2nd : use this ``` (``) ``` for separate it as code

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that the backticks are really only for _inline_ code snippets, not whole blocks of code.